# How do i make a one to one relation where tableB holds the foreign key of tableA and where tableA holds a tableB object in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreign-keys, relation

I have the following entities in a spring boot project:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    private UserInfo info;

}

public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthDay;
}
```

And would like to be able to save a new user like this

```
User user = User.builder()
        .email("example@email.se")
        .password("password")
        .build();
UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.builder()
        .firstName("foo")
        .lastName("oof")
        .birthDate("ofo")
        .build();
user.setInfo(userInfo);
repository.save(user);
```

I've only been working directly with SQL before and in my head i would like to have a table structure that looks like follow:

```
USER TABLE
id
email
password
```

```
USER INFO TABLE
user_id
firstname
lastname
birthday
```

I've tried a few annotations but my boostrapping only works if i use annotations that would make the USER TABLE have a FK to the USER INFO TABLE instead. I'm i missing something here or should i think in another way now when i use spring boot to build my database?

Comment: this feels more like Inheritance with [Joined Table Strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#joined-table)

Comment: @galalem Interesting. Thank you for sharing. Do you know if it's bad practice to use the joined table strategy in this case? never see an example before.